# Starting a task in a certain time

Tags: java

I'm using the following code in order to perform a task every 5 minute.

```
this.timer.schedule(new Send(), new Date(), TEN_SECONDS*6*5);
```

My question is, how can I start my task in this kind of time: xx:00, xx:05, xx:10, xx:15 - in jump of 5 minutes, so I would like to start my task from the nearest 5 minute jump.

Answer (score 2):

you can use quartz.

it is open-source and has cron-like functionality.

http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.1.x/examples/Example3

Comment: Looks like a nice solution but can't I do that by some math calculations?

Comment: doable but it would require more custom coding just to determine which jump of 5 you want.  something like 12:09 would require something more than d1.setMinutes(d1.getMinutes() + 5 - d1.getMinutes()%5);

Comment: Why is that? 9 + 5 - 4 = 10

Comment: you're right ... my last post wasn't clear (i didn't write it fully) ... i was talking about the condition where if you had 12:09:59:999 and by the time you do your calc and set the Timer, you could be past 12:10:00:000.  i didn't realize Timer will immediate run if the date argument is in the past.

Answer (score 0):

It wasn't that hard, really simple math.

```
d1.setMinutes(d1.getMinutes() + 5 - d1.getMinutes()%5);
```